# Cryfs automount using service

Tags: ubuntu, services, systemctl, fuse

I want to mount a cryfs Filesystem automatically after startup.

I installed a new service:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target media-SB01_Cloud.mount 

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/scripts/sb01_cloud_encypted_mount

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This service is installed and running. The Service is calling the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CONTAINER_PASSWORD='XXXXXXXX'

export CRYFS_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo "$CONTAINER_PASSWORD"
echo "$CONTAINER_PASSWORD" | cryfs /media/SB01_Cloud/encrypted /media/SB01_Cloud_Decrypted  -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007
```

But the Filesystem is immediately closed after mount. `systemctl status sb01_cloud_decrypt` shows the following output:

```
Nov 14 21:51:57 host sb01_cloud_encypted_mount[796254]: CryFS Version 0.10.2
Nov 14 21:51:57 host sb01_cloud_encypted_mount[796254]: Password:
Nov 14 21:52:02 host sb01_cloud_encypted_mount[796254]: Deriving encryption key (this can take some time)...done
Nov 14 21:52:02 host sb01_cloud_encypted_mount[796254]: Mounting filesystem. To unmount, call:
Nov 14 21:52:02 host sb01_cloud_encypted_mount[796254]: $ cryfs-unmount "/media/SB01_Cloud_Decrypted"
Nov 14 21:52:02 host cryfs[796303]: Filesystem started.
Nov 14 21:52:02 host cryfs[796303]: Filesystem stopped.
Nov 14 21:52:02 host systemd[1]: sb01_cloud_decrypt.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 21:52:02 host systemd[1]: sb01_cloud_decrypt.service: Consumed 29.059s CPU time.
```

If I call the script from terminal, it is mounting fine and stays mounted. Why do I get this line: `cryfs[796303]: Filesystem stopped.`?

Yes I know the risks of having the password plaintext in the file. And the risks of auto-mounting a encrypted folder, but in this case I just do not trust the original mount. (External Samba Share)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed that the service was stopped, maybe someone can comment why this is terminating a fuse mount.
I was able to fix the issue by adding the `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=true` options to the service.

```
[Unit]
After=network.target media-SB01_Cloud.mount 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/root/scripts/sb01_cloud_encypted_mount

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```